# Is there a way to find out what investment funds have a given stock?

Tags: mutual-funds, etf

Funds usually list their top stock holdings.  Is there a way to do a reverse search so I could find out what mutual funds or ETFs have GOOG, for example, among their top holdings?

Comment: Why? What's the actual goal here? Funds can change their holdings constantly and what you may find today may no longer be true tomorrow. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm aware that funds change their holdings.  I am interested in investing in a sector that does not yet have dedicated funds.  I'd like to investigate which existing funds are in that space by finding which hold key players.

Comment: You could check who holds the shares of the key players... You can find that on EDGAR. It doesn't have to be funds or ETFs (they may hold the shares indirectly).

Comment: @littleadv, that's a good trick I hadn't thought of.

Comment: @espertus, there are more than a few ways that a stock could fit into funds. Market cap as well as growth/value multiples are a couple of criteria beyond sector that is how some funds are constructed.

Comment: "*a sector that does not yet have dedicated funds.*" => what sector is that?

Comment: @assylias, I'm interested in energy storage [http://www.iea.org/newsroomandevents/news/2014/march/opportunitiesandinvestmentforenergystoragetechnologies.html].  I've found a number of funds that specialize in energy or alternative energy but none actively managed with a more narrow focus on the technologies my scientist husband and I most expect to do well, so I'm interested in which of the broader funds invest in the technologies we most expect to do well (of course, there's no guarantee that they or we picked the companies that will actually do well).

Comment: @espertus I don't think that there is an ETF on that theme indeed - the closest you will find are clean tech ETFs but the baterry/storage content will be small, maybe 5/10%. If you want to remain close to your theme you will probably have to buy the stocks yourself...